# Back button to move to specific sheet from where it was called in excel VBA

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets and a help sheet. I want to get back to the sheet from where help sheet was called on pressing a back button on help sheet . Can someone please help me with the code in excel vba?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to capture the sheet name you're currently on, and store is somewhere. For my example, I'm storing it in cell A1 on the help sheet

```
Sub getgelp()

    With Sheets("Help")
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        .Select
    End With

End Sub
```

assign this macro to a button on each page

Then, we need another snippet to then pick up that stored value and go back to it

```
Sub GoBack()

Dim SheetName As String

   SheetName = Sheets("Help").Cells(1, 1).Value
   Sheets(SheetName).Select

End Sub
```

Assign this macro to another button on the help page